# IBM Watson: what should be the right granularity of intent?

Tags: nlp, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

Let's imagine we are opening a restaurant. We use a chatbot to handle customer ordering.

Intent: #order

Entity: @food: burger, noodle, chicken @drinks: coke, water, wine @compliantItem: service, burger, chicken, noodle

Currently I put "I am thirsty, can I order a can of @drinks", and "I am hungry, can I order a @food" in the intent #order. Does any one know if this would confuse Watson?

I am wondering if this should be improved by

1. create a new entity called @menuItem and put 2 values food and drinks in it, while keeping entity @food and @ drinks
2. create a new entity called @menuItem and put all values from @food and @drinks in it and remove entities @food and @drinks
3. maintain 2 intents: (1) #orderfood: put sample "I am hungry, can I order a @food" in the intent #orderfood and (2) #orderdrinks: put sample "I am thirsty, can I order a can of @drinks" in the intent #orderdrinks

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is discussed in "[How entity references are treated](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-intents#intents-entity-as-example)" in the IBM Watson Assistant documentation. You can reference entities as you did. It cancels out any specific examples.

I cannot comment on your intent definitions and improvements. It depends on your dialog flow and how the bot is used. It is learning from user input and how it is processed. If there is something wrong, you as admin can correct it and Watson Assistant would learn it.